# how to develop universal applications in windows

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

I want to know that can I do universal development in windows. I mean can i write code in some-way so that it may run on windows phone 8 and windows store apps  ?
Is there anyway in UI or in code-behind files ?

I want to make application that run on windows phone, windows 8 and tablets.
Please describe !!

Comment: When form factors and input devices are not the same, you can't create univeral application. Not a good one. However, you may consider creating portable class libray to share a common set of code. Just don't expect to have a single application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to code platform specific parts anyway. You can't have the same UI for example.

But you can reduce the amount of code using Portable Class Libraries.

Here you can find some good advices:

- [Sharing Code between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201744.aspx)
- [Co-development for Windows Phone 7/8 and Windows 8 guide](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Co-development_for_Windows_Phone_7/8_and_Windows_8_guide)